# Поиск в DataGrid WPF

Tags: wpf, .net, datagrid

Есть форма на ней есть DataGrid в DataGrid есть 5 колонок (Фамилия,Имя,Отчестно,Телефон,Электронная почта) надо сделать поиск по 3 сразу колонкам либо по 1 (только для колонок Фамилия,Имя,Отчество) если нашло, то красить фон оранжевым, а шрифт черным.
Пример интерфейса:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.12*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" EnableRowVirtualization="False" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="#FFB53351" BorderThickness="2" 
              Margin="5,5,5,6" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID клиента" Visibility="Hidden" Binding="{Binding Client_id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="130" Header="Фамилия" Binding="{Binding Fam}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="130" Header="Имя" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="130" Header="Отчество" Binding="{Binding Otch}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="130" Header="Телефон" Binding="{Binding Phone}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="150" Header="Электронная почта" Binding="{Binding E_mail}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <StackPanel Margin="10 0 5 0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1">
        <ComboBox MinWidth="150" MaxWidth="250">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Фамилия"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Имя"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Отчесто"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Все 3 поля"/>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="SearchBox" Margin="5 0 0 0" MinWidth="200" MaxWidth="250"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Если знаете как сделать такое подскажите пожалуйста уже 2 дня ищу в интернете не могу найти что-то полезное.

Answer (score 0):

Готовый ответ дать - не так интересно, (не факт, но) может быть, не так полезно, дольше и сложнее. В комментариях писать - не поместится. Пишу тут. Но не полный ответ, а наметки.

Странно, что за два дня не нашлось ничего полезного в интернете.

Пишу не ради базы знаний. Советы не выверенные, а то, что сходу пришло на ум. Простите, тут немного сумбурно, не ставил целью хорошее оформление и четкое полное описание. Просто, какие-то соображения.

---

```
public class Person
{
    public string Client_id { get; set; }   //int...?
    public string Fam { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Otch { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string E_mail { get; set; }
}
```

- Правильнее делать через [CollectionViewSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227262/how-to-bind-datagrid-to-collectionviewsource-using-xaml), но, кажется, в данном случае, можно и попроще
- Можно было бы использовать delayed binding text box (например, [вот](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42767/Text-Box-with-Delayed-Binding) какой-то), но буду говорить о варианте попроще

```
public partial class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private /*например, лист*/ List<Person> _DefaultPersons;

    private /*например, лист*/ List<Person> _Persons;
    public /*например, лист*/ List<Person> Persons 
    {  
        get { return _Persons; }
        set
        {
            _Persons = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Persons));
        } 
    }

    private string _SearchWord;
    public string SearchWord
    {
        get { return _SearchWord; }
        set
        {
            _SearchWord = value;
            Persons = FilterPersons(_DefaultPersons);
        }
    }

    //.......
}
```

- Про интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged` можно найти в интернете, здесь его не реализовывал, а использовал `partial`, якобы есть другой файл в котором реализация `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Суть в том, что при изменении свойства вызываем событие о его изменении.
- где-нибудь в конструкторе класса можно инициализировать коллекцию персон
- еще в конструкторе можно присвоить `Persons = _DefaultPersons`
- в методе `FilterPrsons` надо будет написать логику фильтрации списка и поместить этот метод во `ViewModel`. Для начала можно просто сделать какую-нибудь промежуточную проверку, чтобы от общего потом к частному:

```
private List<Person> FilterPrsons()
{
    var result = _DefaultPersons
        .Where(prsn => prsn.Name.Contains(SearchWord))
        .ToList();
    return result;
}
```

- кстати, SearchWord логичнее назвать SearchPhrase
- Приведенная выше `ViewModel` - класс, который в потенциале может стать контекстом данных для того `xaml`-а, который приведен в вопросе. Чтобы он им стал, надо `DataContext`-у `MainWindow` присвоить экземпляр этого класса.
- <strike>Можно</strike> добавить в SearchBox `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, например, так:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchWord, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="50" />
```

- но лучше добавить кнопку / или по клавише Enter, например: [так](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.3.php) или [так](https://programmingistheway.wordpress.com/2015/07/08/wpf-mvvm-binding-command-to-key-press/) или еще как-то. Иначе, если фильтрация долгая (таблица большая), то при каждом введении символа будет тормозить. Можно убрать `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` и без кнопок, без Enter-а, но тогда надо будет после введения фразы кликать в сторону, чтобы был задействован связующий binding.
- суть с командами для кнопки (если кнопка будет) такая, чтобы во `ViewModel`-е было такое свойство, которое являлось бы реализацией `ICommand`, а потом в xaml-е присвоить его свойству кнопки `Command`  эту штуку
- в xaml-е, в таблице `DataGrid` надо прописать такую штуку:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource={Binding Persons}......>
```

- а, да, там же еще есть `ComboBox`.. Можно его тоже привязать к свойствам ViewModel-и, например, (чтобы проще было) иметь там 4 свойства типа `bool`. Потом учитывать эти свойства в методе `FilterPrsons`. Только не забыть про такую методологию:

```
    private bool _x;
    public bool x
    {
        get { return _x; }
        set
        {
            _x = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(X));
        }
    }
```

---

Если делать без ViewModel, прямо в `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, то:

- Можно напрямую там присваивать:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = Persons;
```

- Коллекцию персон можно определить прямо в `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, как и всё остальное на `c#`

```
    private /*например, лист*/ List<Person> _DefaultPersons;

    private /*например, лист*/ List<Person> _Persons;
```

- тогда на `TextBox x:Name="SearchBox"` надо будет повесить событие, например так:

```
<TextBox  TextChanged="textChangedEventHandler"/>
```

- далее

```
private void textChangedEventHandler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{    
    //здесь можно собрать данные из:
    //SearchBox
    //ComboBox (там нет названия, можно присвоить)
    //далее отфильтровать персон методом FilterPersons()
    //далее dataGrid.ItemsSource = _Persons;
}
```

- без `ViewModel` намного проще сделать обработчик для кнопки. Так же как и `<TextBox  TextChanged="textChangedEventHandler"/>`, только там `Button` и событие `Click`, далее если щелкнуть правой или левой кнопке по введенному имени (прямо в редакторе xaml-а) обработчика, то можно перейти к коду / либо посмотреть в интернете про событие `Click` и дописать в `MainWindow.xaml.cs`.

Comment: А можете порекомендовать папку для создания объекта человека. Там же где MVVM?